# Doctrine - postUpdate Event subscriber is not fired for all the documents when inserting multiple documents at a time

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have implemented doctrine event subscriber in symfony with postUpdate event.I am trying to print my document id in postUpdate event.This works fine if I am inserting single document. Problem comes when i try to insert a set of 30 documents at a time. Problem is only one document id is getting printedthough i am inserting 30 documents at a time.

Below is the code i have implemented.

**services.yml**

```
KonnectEz.doctrine.listener:
    class: KonnectEz\CoreBundle\Foundation\EventListener\DoctrineSubscriber
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
    tags:
        -  { name: doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_subscriber}
```

**Doctrine event subscriber:**

```
namespace KonnectEz\CoreBundle\Foundation\EventListener;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use KonnectEz\CoreBundle\Document\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class DoctrineSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {

    private $container = null;
    private $userHelperService = null;

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents() {
         return array(
            Events::postUpdate,
        );
    }


     public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
             error_log("Entity Id:".$entity->getId());
        }

    }
}
```

I have a function where i am doing flush on a set of 30 documents at a time. That is

```
$totalEntitiesCount = sizeof($entities);
$entityCount = 0;
if ($entityCount == 30 || $entityCount == $totalEntitiesCount) {
     $dm->flush();
     $entityCount = 0;
}
```

Why postUpdate event is not getting called for each document that is getting inserted?
I want this event to be called for each document that is getting inserted.How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postUpdate` is called when you update an existing object of an entity.

If you want changes to happen after insert, add a `postPersist` or a `postFlush` event instead.

You will find details on doctrine events here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html (mongoDB Version)

Moreover, I would also turn x-debug on, with a breakpoint inside the eventListener piece, to see if it is triggered at all.